# Using Sunspot to generate index views - is that smart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

We are currently developing in app in which a number of 'index'-views make use of a lot of virtual attributes. At the same time we require full_text search functionality.

The solution we have chosen is to use Sunspot/Solr to index the models, including the virtual attributes. We then use Sunspot to retrieve the correct records, sort them, search them etc. This all works quite well in our development setup.

Obviously, this approach requires us to keep the Solr-index in sync with the database, or f.e. a user would not see his newly created record listed on the index page. To achieve this, we force index actions at various points in the app.

Before we build this solution out, I just wanted to check if there are concerns with using Sunspot this way. Particularly, if the app gets bigger will having to keep the index in perfect sync start to take its toll?

It seems like a very nice way of dealing with virtual attributes in index pages, but I want to make sure it isn't to good to be true...

Thanks for our help
Erwin

Answer (score 0):

A commit is a heavy operation in Solr and you don't want to do it to often. If it is possible don't have commit triggered on a user activated function since this might put a lot of stress on your servers as the user base grows (and some users are evil).

If you can, set the server to autocommit every x seconds (depending on the size of the index and the load on the server). This way you wont have a commit-flood while keeping the delay at a known max interval.